# SSO by Identity Server in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to work without login page redirection in API manager when I have logged in session in Identity server. But I had to login with separate login pages for Is, Carbon in APIM, dev portal and publisher.

I want to have a single sign on for all WSO2 applications making the login page as the login page of my web application instead of default oauth2 login page. I want to know is it possible to have a SSO for WSO2 applications with a custom login page and how to enable it if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by configuring Identity Server as the IDP for SSO.

First, you need to **configure APIM as a service provider in the IS**. Ensure that when you create the SP, you tick the SaaS application checkbox.

In the **Inbound Authentication** Configuration section, you have to set up the **SAML2 Web SSO** Configuration.

Then, you have to **configure IS as an IDP in the API Manager**.

If you're already logged into the Publisher/Dev Portals, it will create SPs for those portals in the API Manager. For the Carbon console, you need to separately create an SP similar to the portals.

For all the portals' SPs, go to the **Local and Outbound Authentication** Configuration and select the Identity Provider as the **Federated Authentication**, and check **Assert identity using mapped local subject identifier**.

You can find more information with a screenshot guide in the documentation[1]

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/extending-api-manager/saml2-sso/configuring-identity-server-as-idp-for-sso/